# Whiteboard marker stain cleanup from textbook

Tags: cleaning

I accidently dropped white board marker on my textbook and unfortunately it landed on its tip. so now there is a big stain on the page. any ideas that how can i remove it. i tried eraser. actually textbook is pretty important.

Comment: Try a solvent, such as acetone or ethyl-methyl ketone (nail-polish remover), with a pad of paper towel underneath to absorb the ink. It might work, make the stain a bit lighter, or do nothing. *Caution!* Flammable.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own textbook, and you are in a study class where others have the same book:

- photocopy the stained page front and back from a borrowed copy
- if you can, copy to both sides of a single sheet of paper
- cut off the damaged page leaving enough to tape to
- use clear tape to overlay the stained page
- cut off excess paper to be smaller than other pages, so it doesn't protrude

Comment: Ohh so no way to remove the stain? lol thanks btw